# Sort directory list in reverse order

Tags: pipe, ls, sort

I'm trying to sort directory list in reverse alphabetical order.

Why do I get a random order ?

```bsh
    ls -l /usr/bin/ | sort -r
```

Edit : I'm obliged to use the command sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sort using the entire string as a key.

The object names are written in the 9th column, so it is necessary to use:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ | sort -k9 -r
```

Comment: Note that `ls` also outputs a line saying `total`, followed by a number.  This solution seems to ignore that line and will likely output it last rather than first.  It would make more sense to use `ls -l /usr/bin | tac` as it would be quicker to type (the final output might be different unless you're in the POSIX locale though).

Answer (score 2):

Let `ls` do the sorting:

```bsh
ls -l -r /usr/bin
```

or just

```bsh
ls -lr /usr/bin
```

The standard `-r` option to `ls` make it sort the list in the reverse order to what it would otherwise do. If you ask `ls` to sort on the modification timestamp with `-t`, `-r` will reverse the order of that list too, etc.

Your command pipeline sorts on the permissions, ownership, etc. that `ls -l` outputs, and would not consider the filenames unless all other information for two entries were identical.

---

You did not ask about this, but since it's a common thing to want to do and often the next step after asking about `ls` output ordering... To actually extract the filenames sorting first or last from a directory listing, [don't use `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985), instead use an array or the positional parameters:

The first filename:

```bsh
names=(/usr/bin/*)
printf '%s\n' "${names[0]}"
```

or

```
set -- /usr/bin/*
printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

The last filename:

```bsh
names=(/usr/bin/*)
printf '%s\n' "${names[-1]}"
```

or

```bsh
set -- /usr/bin/*
shift "$(( $# - 1 ))"
printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

Likewise, the best way to get the most recently modified file (or directory) in `bash` would be to do

```bsh
set -- /usr/bin/*
newest=$1; shift
for pathname do
    [ "$pathname" -nt "$newest" ] && newest=$pathname
done

printf 'Newest: %s\n' "$newest"
```

Change the `-nt` test to `-ot` to get the oldest (least recently modified) file.